# running server in development mode in rails with error screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I try to use server in development mode that gives errors on html page instead of the message "We're sorry, but something went wrong.". It starts in development mode but it does not give the error information and still gives the same silly message. How can I make it open the error info. on html page when an error is occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your environment file either development.rb or production.rb do this:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```